# Specific counter example of a function from a sample space to the real line that is not a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In a random variable the Borel sets of the real line have a pre-image in the sigma algebra (measurable). This differentiates random variables from other functions from the sample space to the real line that could be defined, and allows assigning a probability measure to open intervals in the real line.

I am asking for an example, or several examples if possible, of functions from the outcomes of random experiments (sample space) to the real line that are not random variables.

Comment: Any non-measurable function will do.

Comment: @NapD.Lover that is where I am stuck in the definitions, and why I would appreciate some concrete examples.

Comment: It depends on your underlying $\sigma$-algebra. Consider for example the trivial case where the probability space is $(\Omega , \lbrace \emptyset ,\Omega \rbrace)$. Then any non-constant function will not be measurable.

Comment: If you take $\Omega=[0,1]$, and the $\sigma$-algebra of the probability triple to be the Borel sets of the unit interval, then for any non measurable set $A\subset [0,1]$, the function $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ is non-measurable. I cannot recall anymore interesting examples at the top of my head though (and this requires you to know how to find a non-measurable set).